# What is the correct answer to "alles klar"?

Tags: phrase, colloquial

When someone asks me

> *"alles klar?"*

what should I answer?

I would like to say something more than *"ja"*. Is there a way to ask if they are doing ok too?

Comment: "Alles klar?" (You all right?) is like asking "Geht's dir gut?". When you just ask "Wie geht's dir?" (How are you?) you ask neutral, but asking "Alles klar?" you ask for the positive answer. You expect that the other is all right and will say "yes".

Comment: @Em1 I don't quite agree with "Alles klar?" asking for the positive answer. I would say this depends on who is asking whom, in what context, with what tone etc... Or I have been using it wrongly half of the time which is very possible of course...

Comment: One of my teachers used to say: "Alles klar, alles klärchen... schöne Grüße ans Klärchen!" ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any of the following would sound natural:

- "Ja, und bei Dir/Ihnen?"
- "Danke, und bei Dir/Ihnen?"
- "Danke, und selbst?"
- "Ja, alles klar, danke, und bei Dir?"

Comment: or to make a joke you can say ... "wie Kloßbrühe" :)

Comment: I've always preferred "wie dicke Tinte", myself :)

Comment: Man kann nicht durch klumpige Brühe sehen, und durch Tinte auch nicht. Man kann aber dicke Buchstabieren gut lesen. Sie sind deutlich...
Die Metapher---"klar" wie Glas, und darum Verständnis?---ist mir nicht klar, wenn ich darüber logischerweise denke.

Comment: Das ist der Punkt. Sogar Deutsche sind ironiebefaehigt.

Comment: @diN0bot Ich grüble gerade darüber nach, was diese dicken Buchstabieren wohl sein könnten. :-)

Answer (score 8):

I have heard people saying:

> "Ja, muss"

Comment: Welcome to GLU. Please only respond to questions by comments when you don't want to answer the question itself.

Comment: Without the additional question this is a useful answer. People do reply with *"Ja, muss"* or *"Es muss"* on *"Alles klar?"* or *"Wie geht's?"*.

Comment: And if you don't have enough reputation for posting comments (50 is needed), then you can ask a new question!

Comment: @Takkat, Em1 and Hendrik Vogt Thank you so much :) 
I'll follow the rules :) Dankeschon

Comment: In the accepted answer "Danke, und selbst?" is mentioned. If I'm right I have also heard people using "Ja, und selber" is that right too or is that same. @Takkat please do edit.

Comment: @user1264624: "Ja, und selber" is correct, too, and it is essentially the same. ("selber" is the colloquial version of "selbst".)

Comment: +1 for "ja, muss". This is the answer which I usually give to indicate that I'm stressed out. But if I think about it, it is probably a stupid thing to say, because there is (fortunately?) no law to feel good.

Comment: I sense *Ja, muss* as an unpleasant mixture of trying to be ironic, telling an old joke for the 1000th time and feeling explicitly sorry for oneself.

Comment: _Ja, muss_ is something I hear exceedingly often. Almost standard nowadays, especially or specifically in the Rhineland, when I visit there. Just saying, whether some commenters like it or not, or think it's idiotic or not. Heck, it's become the SYN-ACK of communication when I call family on Skype up there! Generally something like _Wie geht et?_ -> _Jo, mutt so_.

Answer (score 6):

Mir fallen 3 unterschiedliche Situationen ein, in denen "Alles klar" gefragt wird.

- Der andere bemerkt an einem Seufzen, am Gesichtsausdruck oder sonstwie, dass ich traurig oder betrübt bin, verletzt, krank oder sorgenvoll und zeigt ein echtes Interesse und die Bereitschaft Zuwendung zu spenden.
- Der andere fragt ohne persönliches Interesse im Rahmen routinierter Kontrolle nach, ob bei mir alles in Ordnung ist. Er würde sich nicht um mich kümmern wollen, aber um das Problem, das ich mit der Zündung der Triebwerke habe, oder mit dem 3¼-zölligen Müffelstück.
- Der häufigste Fall: Der andere benutzt eine Floskel im Stile von ''Hallo''; es ist nur eine unverbindliche Begrüßung.

Es gibt sicher weitere Situationen, in denen man 'Alles klar?' fragen kann. Für alle Situationen gibt es viele Nuancen, mit denen die Frage formuliert werden kann; es kann eine Bedrohung in der Frage mitschwingen, weil ich vielleicht Schuld bin, wenn nicht alles klar ist, es kann aufdringlich sein, sowie oberflächlich, einfühlsam, dezent, aufmunternd, provozierend, ...

Und als autonomer Bürger kann ich souverän darauf reagieren, und sagen was ich will - das hängt natürlich von der Situation ab: Meiner Beziehung zu der Person, meiner Befindlichkeit, meinen Absichten, usw.

Nur für die Floskel läßt sich eine Vielzahl an anderen Floskeln angeben, mit denen häufig reagiert wird.

- Auf jeden Fall!
- Selbstverständlich/Selbstredend!
- Natürlich!
- Und wie!
- Aber immer! (Aber logisch! (umgsspr.:) Aber hallo!)
- Klar doch! (umgsspr.: Klaro!)
- Klar wie Kloßbrühe (umgsspr.)

Answer (score 2):

There are many options how you can answer this. Some are:

- Sicher!
- Ja, sicher.
- Ja, klar!
- Sicher; bei Dir auch?

Answer (score 2):

Eine gute Antwort ist

> Alles klar.